# Best way to store an item dimensions in a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an application that users will be typing item dimensions such as width, height, depth and also weight of the item.

```
public class ItemDimensions{

 public int width {get;set;}
 public int height {get;set;}
 public int depth {get;set;}
 public int weight {get;set;}

}
```

First question is what should be the best value type to store these dimensions in the database? int string double decimal ..?

On the user interface users will be given an option to select dimension type to enter details. For example they might choose to enter cm or inches. for weight they might choose to enter kg gr or stone ect. What would be the best way of approaching this issue? Ideally I will be storing only one value instead of creating an extra column for each different dimension type.

My own approach is to create a dimensionType table and when the user selects the dimension lets say for width height and depth as cm it will keep a foreign key the type of the dimension and it will store the data. then lets say if the user would like to view it in inches it will check the type of the data and convert it. Is this a right approach to these types of dimensions data or there is a better way of handling these?

Comment: If you do create a table of units and conversion factors you should consider tagging them so you'll know which are applicable to a given measurement, e.g. lengths, masses, times, ... . That way you can avoid trying to crate an item that is 6 barns by 1 fortnight by 9 stones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb store your data in a standardized format, whether it's physical measures like length/width/height/weight or date/time information.  If you're expecting different units or formats (or time zones), do some conversion before you store the data so that you know that it's in a reliable, usable format.

A measurement is composed of two pieces of information: a value and a unit specifier.  If you want the user to be able to choose the units when entering the value then you have to make the decision about whether you want to store the measurement in its original [value,unit] format or convert the entered data into a standardized unit and just store the converted value.

For example, let's say I enter a length value of `1.5 inch`.  You could store the value in two fields (`LengthValue` and `LengthUnit` for instance) or you could decide to convert the value to a standard unit (meters for instance) and store it in a single `Length` field with the value `0.0381`.  If the user wants to see the value again you either give it to him in meters or use your conversion methods to translate it into the units of her choice.

The advantage of a standard representation for the data is that it makes it possible to ask simple questions of the data like 'How many items have a length between 150mm and 300mm?':

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Items
WHERE Length BETWEEN 0.150 AND 0.300
```

Or how about the average weight of all items that are under 1 cubic meter in volume?

```
SELECT AVG(Weight)
FROM Items
WHERE (Length * Width * Height) < 1
```

If you want to store [value, unit] then you'll need a conversion table to allow you to ask those questions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT i.LengthValue * c.Factor AS Length
    FROM Items i
    JOIN Conversion c ON c.FromUnit = i.LengthUnit
    WHERE i.ToUnit = 'm'
) l
WHERE Length BETWEEN 0.150 AND 0.300
```

And the much more complicated:

```
SELECT AVG(WeightKg)
FROM
(
    SELECT i.LengthValue * lc.Factor AS LengthM,
        i.WidthValue * wc.Factor AS WidthM,
        i.HeightValue * hc.Factor AS HeightM,
        i.WeightValue * mc.Factor AS WeightKg
    FROM Items i
    JOIN Conversion lc ON lc.FromUnit = i.LengthUnit
    JOIN Conversion wc ON wc.FromUnit = i.WidthUnit
    JOIN Conversion hc ON hc.FromUnit = i.HeightUnit
    JOIN Conversion mc ON mc.FromUnit = i.WeightUnit -- 'm' for 'mass'
    WHERE lc.ToUnit = 'm' AND wc.ToUnit = 'm' AND hc.ToUnit = 'm' 
        AND mc.ToUnit = 'Kg'
) d
WHERE (LengthM * WidthM * HeightM) < 1
```

Seems like a contrived example, but I've seen code like this in production.

Not only is this ugly code, it is terribly inefficient.  Even if you store the unit specifier as an index into a units table or as an index into your conversion table, the query complexity is still too high.

And the downside here is that if you're allowing different units in the database, you *have* to do this sort of thing for *every* query that uses those values.  Even if you know that every *current* length value in the database has been entered in `m`, you can't guarantee that this will always be the case.

Comment: First of all thanks for the clear explanation and telling what is the downside of going for the second approach. I agree that I should convert the value before I save it as a standard format. However, I believe that I also somehow need to store the unit that user selects. so if that user views the details I would like to remember his/her choice and show it to that user in the unit that user selected. So somehow I will be combining the @Szymon answer with yours. And lastly how about the value format? what would be the best to store those dimensions? what would you recommend? Thanks

Comment: I tend to be pretty agnostic about the value format.  Personally I tend to use FLOAT fields, but largely because I'm lazy :P

Comment: One thing you should be careful about with conversions: they may result in loss of precission or values that are different to what the user entered (especially if you use `FLOAT` data type). Whether it's a problem for you or not, it depends on your specific needs.

Comment: @Szymon Very true, but the fixed point types (`decimal` and `numeric`) have their own problems with precision that make them unusable for a lot of situations, IMO.  Especially with conversion factors being what they are, fixed-point just doesn't give the sort of flexibility I prefer.

Comment: @akdurmus regarding the fetch-as-unit thing... an application-wide per-user setting for units is probably the simplest option.  Have the application handle the unit translation, leave the database to just store the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would adopt the same approach as you. You can store the items in the main table together with their type. Your model uses `int` for dimentions but would you allow decimal values as well - the best type to store it in SQL Server would be `decimal`.

You could have the main table

```
Item table
--
... -- other fields
Width decimal(38,6) -- you can decide on precision
Height decimal(38,6) -- you can decide on precision
Depth decimal(38,6) -- you can decide on precision
DimentionTypeId int FK -- the 3 above would use the same dimention type?
Weight


DimentionType table
--
DimentionTypeID int PK
Description
... -- other fields
```

You can use `DimentionType` for lookups in your application (e.g. to populate combo boxes with dimention types).